# Pass different responses from server in different Activities

Tags: java, android, sockets, android-activity, android-service

I'm trying to create Android app which will use multiple activities and one socket for all of them. I understood that I should use `Service` which will contain socket which will be connected to the server. Every `Activity` will be use some specific requests to the server(e.g. first Activity can load users and second can send them messages). So how can I navigate the responses from the server between Activities(e.g. list of users will be passed to the first `Activity`, and messages will be loaded to the second `Activity`)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you say you are using `Service` for loading data from server ,after getting data you can handle response depending on type of response you fire `LocalBroadcast` and receive that in activity using dynamic `BroadcastReceiver`

See tutorial for [LocalBrodcast](http://www.sanfoundry.com/java-android-program-demonstrate-local-broadcast-manager/)

Comment: Thanks, I will check this solution, but I want to clarify this: so, I will store socket in service which will be bound with the instance of the Application. All Activities will be call get method in the Application which will return service. But what if my Activity will request the service before it will be bound? How can I prevent it? And maybe you can advise some better way do this thing?

Comment: But what if my Activity will request the service before it will be bound? i don't understand  what exactly you mean to say ?

Comment: I meant if my Activity will try to call methods in service before service will be bound. E.g. I launch the app, after that app starts Application and Activity, in Application::onCreate() I have bindService(), in Activity::onCreate() I have `service = ((AppCore) this.getApplication()).getService();` but if service still not bound then I will get null in `service`.

Comment: for that you can try getting service after some sec 0r mili sec  , for waiting use `Handler`.  the logic mainly goes like this  `if(service!=null ){ //do  work}else{// wait for 2 sec again try }`

Comment: I thought about it, but this looks not like the best solution... Maybe this type of using socket can be done using another architecture?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118281/discussion-between-n-j-and-don-prog).

Answer (score 0):

Your Service can be a router for your Activities. By specific response (map it to switch-case ids) it will start proper Activity. A started Activity can bind to the Service for chatting.

Comment: Play with intent flags ex. [FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT)